# IE7 losing my h3

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, html

My page looks great in safari, chrome, ff, and degrades gracefully in IE8, but my client requires IE7 as well.

The one little thing that isnt' working is my H3. Strangely, my H2 works fine. It's not a matter of losing style, which seems to be a more common issue seen; the H3 just doesn't show up at all! I've researched this a good bit and tried many things I've seen recommended for missing styles (including the zoom:1), but I haven't been able to fix this issue. My best guess is it has something to do with the nested divs...

I've also tried various doctypes, to no avail...including:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">   

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Here's my fiddle (with more complete code), along with a portion below: http://jsfiddle.net/cathi/2Kkh2/18/ (of course it seems to work fine here - can't bring up jsfiddle on the machine with IE7 here. hmm...)

```
h2 {
    color:#007cc0; 
    font-size:1.4em;
    line-height:1.9em;
    font-family:'Tahoma',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-bottom:0;
    font-weight:normal;
}

h3 {
    color:#ea752e; 
    font-size:1.4em;
    line-height:1.9em;
    font-family:'Tahoma',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-bottom:0;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

and, the html (copying some, but not nec all of the divs)

```
<div class="content-intro">
  <h2>Here is my H2 that shows up fine in IE7</h2>
<p>A paragraph of intro copy here</p>
</div>
<div class="content-checklists">
```

#### This is my H3 that is not showing up in IE7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this strange behaviour is because of IE7's occasionally (or should I say frequently?) erroneous way of handling values when floats are involved. Ultimately, your `<h3>` is pushed below the icon image, and since there is an `overflow:hidden` on the parent, the element just doesn't show up (unless you scroll down in its parent somehow).

In your definition of `.content-checklists-title`, try removing your `width:97%`.

This should still result in the desired behaviour in other browsers (thanks to the way that text flows around floated elements), but will also avoid IE7's funny quirks.

I hope this is what you were looking for! If not, let me know and I'll be happy to try helping further!

Comment: Fantastic!! that worked! What I do sacrifice (not huge... but still) is the bottom border - previously set at 97% so that it wouldn't butt up against the right sidebar. But in the grand scheme of things, not a bad thing to compromise. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, great! I'm glad this helped you out.